# Mobile safari out of memory during video capturing

Tags: javascript, react-native, html5-canvas, webrtc, mobile-safari

I have React class with two main elements. Canvas and video.
I get video stream and render it at 30fps to canvas.

```
class GetImage extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.constraints = {
      video: {
        width: { ideal: 2048 },
        height: { ideal: 1080 },
        facingMode: {
          exact: 'environment'
        }
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setVideo(this.video, this.constraints, this.readyToPlayVideo)
  }

  capture = () => {
    const { video } = this
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight

    let context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    this.setState({ capture: canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg') })
    stopVideo()
  }


  readyToPlayVideo = () => {
    const { canvas, video }  = this
    const { offsetHeight, offsetWidth } = video
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    ctx.canvas.setAttribute('height', offsetHeight)
    ctx.canvas.setAttribute('width', offsetWidth)

    const timeout = 1000 / 30 // drawing at 30fps

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    let _listener = () => {
      (function loop() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0)
        setTimeout(loop, timeout)
      })()
    }

    _listener();
  }


  retake = () =>
    this.setState({ capture: null },
      () => {
        setVideo(this.video, this.constraints, this.readyToPlayVideo, this.handleError)
      }
    )

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <video
            style={{ visibility: 'hidden'}}
            ref={video => (this.video = video)}
            playsInline
            autoPlay
          />
          <canvas ref={canvas => (this.canvas = canvas)}/>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So far so good.
But I faced a problem with mobile Safari. Looks like it keep every Canvas object ever created in memory.

After several pictures was taken Safari crashes with "out of memory".
I already do clearRect before rendering a new image, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues to address here. Firstly, you seem to have a circular reference in your `loop` function; you are calling the function within the function.

Because of this, the autoplay the video (when rendering) won't stop .. causing the 'out of memory' error.

Also , I think best practice would be to create a `componentDidUnmount` function that destroys the video (when no longer needed). Use `.dispose` to destroy the video.

Hope this helps

Comment: Here's some sample ['dispose' code](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-react.html) from the react docs

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, circular reference doesn't look nice. Fixed that.

But I'm not sure how to really destroy a video.
React destroys video tag based on component state, so unmountComponentAtNode isn't a solution.

And I don't use videojs from your link.
I'm rendering video or not based on component state and looks like problem is here. Every time then I'm starting a new video I get +20-100mb of memory usage.

Comment: @lasfin  here's a [5-step  guide to destroying classes](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/destroy-all-classes-turn-react-components-inside-out-with-functional-programming/).. it's a bit long, but gives good examples. A few tweaks to your codes would be all that is required. Hope this helps.

Comment: @lasfin It may help if you cleared your timeout on componentDidUnmount, e.g. let (set it) .. let yourvar = setTimeout(loop, timeout);
(then in unMount)... clearTimeout(yourvar);

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this will 100% solve your problem, however, this may help. Instead of using `setInterval` for your animations, use `window.requestAnimationFrame`.

Here's an example

```
var requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
            function( callback ) {
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 30);
            };
})();

function loop(){
     requestAnimFrame(loop);
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
     ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
     setTimeout(loop, timeout);
}
loop();
```

Once again, I'm not 100% sure this will solve your issue, however, it may help. Let me know if you have any more questions.

I hope this helps!